# Is there a formal way of defining a Zeno Machine?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, hypercomputation

The idea of a Zeno machine is pretty interesting to me, but I can't seem to find a formal definition for how a Zeno machine would work.  I can find a couple of definitions around but they are all about the same (I suspect that everyone is cribbing off of each other) and lack any real formalism.  A fairly representative definition is this one from [the relevant wikipedium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno_machine)

> More formally, a Zeno machine is a Turing machine that takes $2^{-n}$ units of time to perform its $n$-th step; thus, the first step takes $0.5$ units of time, the second takes $0.25$, the third $0.125$ and so on, so that after one unit of time, a countably infinite (i.e. $\aleph_0$) number of steps will have been performed.

This definitions is a little weird.

The biggest reason this definition is lacking is that the description doesn't really tell us anything about the state of the machine at any time $t \geq 1$.

Now if we look at an example of some psuedo-code for an accelerated Turing machine we have a bit of a conflict. Here is a sample slightly modified from [C. Calude, L. Staiger. *A Note On Accelerated Turing Machines*](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/research/groups/CDMTCS/researchreports/350cris.pdf)

> ```
> begin program
>   write 0 on the first position of the output tape
>   set i = 1
>   begin loop
>     simulate the first i steps of T on w
>     if T(w) has halted,
>     then
>       write 1 on the first position of the output tape
>     set i = i + 1
>   end loop
> end program
> ```

Now this sample is intended to solve the halting problem on a Turing Machine.  And according to the authors:

> By inspecting the first position of the output tape we need one unit of time to run the above machine in order to decide whether $T(w)$ stops or not

Now here we are relying on some notion of the state of the machine at time $t=1$, which is out of the scope of our definition.

Now the intuitive patch here is to say that the state at time $t=1$ is just the limit of the states as time approaches $1$.<sup>[1]</sup>  But there are some problems with this the most important being that not all sequences will converge.  Take for example the following pseudo-code:

> ```
> begin program
>   set i = 1
>   begin loop
>     write i on the first position of the output tape
>     if i is 1,
>     then
>       set i = 0
>     else
>       set i = 1
>   end loop
> end program
> ```

The sequence of states here cannot converge (regardless of how we choose our metric) and thus this naïve patch does not completely fix the problem.

Is there a way of defining a Zeno machine that is formal and complete?

---

<sup>[1] : In fact while I was putting this question together I found [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9710052.pdf) which pretty much outright states this definition.</sup>

Comment: Take a look at [Hamkins' survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0212047).

Comment: There's also the notion of [limit computability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_in_the_limit), which has a "classical computability" characterization: something is limit-computable iff it is computable [relative to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction) the halting problem.

Answer (score 3):

Hamkins' survey [*Infinite time Turing machines*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0212047.pdf), linked by [Yuval Filmus](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/683/yuval-filmus), formally defines a computational model (Infinite time Turing machine) that meets the requirements of a Zeno machine.

The definition of ITTMs does not use the time based framing; instead it is an extension of classical binary **TM**s to be defined at transfinite ordinals.  A classical **TM** has a start status (empty tape, etc.) and a function to get the successive status; a **ITTM** just adds the status of the machine at limit ordinals.

Rather than taking the *limit* of the cells in the tape, as suggested and refuted in the question, we take the *limit supremum*.  Formally for

$$
T(\lambda)_k = \limsup_{n\rightarrow \lambda} T(n)_k
$$

where $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal, $k$ is the index of some cell, and $T$ is the function that gives the tape at some numbered step.

The $\limsup$ ensures that it will always be defined for any sequence (since the alphabet is bounded).  If the normal limit does not converge for some cell then (for a binary alphabet) the cell at time $\lambda$ will be $1$, since in order for it to not converge it must be $1$ at an infinite number of steps.

The state and the location of the read head are resolved much more simply.  Just as there is a start state, there is also a limit state.  At times corresponding to limit ordinals the machine is in the limit state, and the read head is set to the beginning of the tape.

---

The linked paper does not even mention "Zeno machine" (although it mentions Zeno) and **ITTM**s may not be the only formal model of a Zeno machine possible (beyond trivial modifications).  However it is *a* model of computation that allows a Turing machine to perform an infinite number of operations and then continue calculations, so if you are looking for a formal way to talk about Zeno Machines **ITTM**s work just fine.